# Command "git status -u no" filters tracked files also

Tags: git

I want to see the status of the working directory and the index but not untracked files.

The git-status doc http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html tells that the -u switch will filter untracked files.

But the following command

```
git status -u no
```

filters untracked files and also filters the modifications of the tracked files in the working tree and the index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
git status --untracked-files=no
```

The complete argument form works.
But actually, if you are using the abbreviation, you need to **remove the space** between `-u` and the mode:

```
git status -uno
```

[Oleh Prypin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/241039/oleh-prypin) helpfully [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008546/command-git-status-u-no-filters-tracked-files-also/7008729#comment82985912_7008729) that [`git status -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status--ultmodegt) accepts an optional argument (defaults to `all`).
`-u no` would be ambiguous just like `--untracked-files no`, because `git status -u some_file.txt` has to keep working.

Comment: The reason for this is that `-u` accepts an *optional* argument (defaults to `all`). `-u no` would be ambiguous just like `--untracked-files no`, because `git status -u some_file.txt` has to keep working.

Comment: @OlehPrypin Thank you. Very good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.