# is it possible to `git status` only modified files?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-status

Is it possible to have `git status` only show the modified files due, in my case, to having too many staged files?

Comment: How do you have a scroll limit? By default, `git status` will invoke the pager.

Comment: Sorry scrollback limit is set to 512 lines on my machine. I guess i could change it; but would prefer a one line command to view just modified files in the status because GD/imagecache will generate even more files eventually.

Comment: Right... my point is the pager doesn't use your terminal's scrollback.

Comment: Anything wrong with just grepping for whatever you find interesting?  Use `--short` or `--porcelain` to get one-line versions of the status.

Comment: One more point, based on the suggestion to use `git ls-files -m`: which modification(s) do you care about, staged, unstaged, or both?

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You can't do this with `git status`, but you could use `git ls-files -m` to show all modified files.

Comment: Just so others know, this will only show files which have been modified without yet being staged.

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, it has inaccurate information.  You can "'git status' only modified files" with `git status | grep modified` just as user23186 indicates in their answer.

Comment: @K.AlanBates My answer is correct. Your command is not running `git status` only on modified files, it's running `git status` on everything and then using a separate tool to throw away the unwanted info. Your answer also won't work if the user has the git config setting to always use short mode. A more accurate suggestion would have been `git status -s | grep '^.M'`, but even that is just a poor way of accomplishing the same thing as `git ls-files -m`.

Comment: To be more specific, the mention of 'inaccurate information' is only to your first clause declaring that "you can't do this with `git status`." You totally can have git status return only modified files with grep.  Of course your  suggestion to use `ls-files -m` will function just fine; its just not as expressive, in my opinion.

Comment: For me, `git ls-files -m` is not showing anything but `git status | grep modified` is working.

Comment: @KevinBallard Can you give all option of `git ls-files`?

Comment: As others have pointed out, this only shows unstaged files. If you want to show both unstaged AND staged files, this is the best answer I've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39994894/452587

Comment: @thdoan There are a number of options for showing staged files, though this particular question seems to want to explicitly exclude staged files. `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M HEAD` would show just modified files for both staged and unstaged, though you should check the docs on `--diff-filter` to see what other filter types you might want to add.

Comment: For better or worse, this solution will only show modified files in your current directory or its subdirectories.  In other words, if you're in a subdirectory, it will not show you the modified files in your parent directory.  IMO this is a drawback but I guess it's fine as long as you're aware of this fact.  I suspect this is the explanation for Sandeepan Nath's comment and its numerous upvotes.  I am surprised this hasn't been pointed out in 8 years.

Answer (score 80):

It looks like `git status -uno` will show you only files that git is tracking, without showing anything else in the directory. Not exactly what you asked for, but perhaps accomplishes the same thing (getting a readable-length list of files that git tracks).

Comment: `git status -u no` does not show (1) tracked files which are modified, nor (2) tracked files which are staged. I've verified this with git versions 1.8.5.2 and 1.9.4.

Comment: @TomNysetvold, you may actually mean `git status -uno` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008546/command-git-status-u-no-filters-tracked-files-also)

Answer (score 39):

For modified files:

```
git status | grep modified:
```

Comment: So useful I've created an alias for this: `git config --global alias.modified '!git status | grep modified:'`

Comment: It's better to use `git status -uno`.  If you prefer more terse output, then use `git status -s -uno` or `git status -suno`.  Note: It's **_VERY IMPORTANT_** not to use a space between the `-u` option and its argument, `no`.

Answer (score 35):

```
git status -s | awk '{if ($1 == "M") print $2}'
```

Comment: Or `awk '$1 == "M" { print $2 }'`

Answer (score 25):

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M`

Comment: I recommend those filters: `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR` which does Added, Copied, Modified and Renamed files.

Answer (score 11):

`git diff --name-only` works too.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
$ git status -uno
```

to list only modified files.

Answer (score 6):

To list the modified files use:

```
git ls-files -m
```

If you want just the basename (no path) then you can pipe each result to the basename command using xargs, line by line:

```
git ls-files -m | xargs -L 1 basename
```

Comment: Clever use of the xargs for ditching the path. That's got applications extending WAY beyond this particular use-case. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the same info and found following gives modified files:

```
git status -uno
```

Comment: `git status -uno --porcelain` adds nice output for parsing script

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is i have too many staged files that i don't want to commit or gitignore at the moment and i can't scroll up.

While this may not directly answer the question of listing only modified files, it may help limit the number of files that are listed.

You can pass a path to `git status` to limit the output to a specific folder in the repo.

For example:

```
git status app
git status spec
git status src/components
```

Answer (score 3):

### Update

open the `.gitconfig`

```sh
[user]
     name = ...
     email = ...
[alias]
    #  add below code
    mySt = "!f() {\
        inputType=${1:-" "};\
        git status -s | grep "\\ $inputType" |\
        sed -e 's/ / /'   ;\
    }; f"
```

explain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772985/9935654

usage

> `git mySt M`       : show modified:
>
> `git mySt M *.md`  : Show all *.md, which was modified.
>
> `git mySt D`       : deleted:
>
> `git mySt`         : same as the `git status -s`

---

### OS: windows

The following command will display all lines containing **"modified:"**, **"renamed:"** or **"new file:"**

```
git status | findstr "modified: renamed: new file:"
```

If you want to specified file type: (for example `*.py` `*.ini`)

```
git status *.py *.ini | findstr "modified: renamed: new file:"
```

If you think it’s too much trouble typing so much:

1. create a batch file (for example: `st.bat`)
2. write contents as following:

   ```
   @echo off
   :: st.bat  (this line doesn't necessarily. ( just let you know the scripts name.))
   git status %~1 | findstr "modified: renamed: new file:"
   ```
3. add environment path which contains your batch file. (`st.bat`)
4. usage

   ```
   st.bat "*.py *.ini"
   ```

   (note: if type > 1 then must add the semicolon)

### OS: LINUX

as @Lance says you can try

`git status | grep modified:`

Answer (score 3):

I use this command :

```bash
$ git status -sb -uno | grep -v "^\sD\s"
```

And the output looks like this :

```bash
## master...origin/master
 M GNUmakefile
 M include/mp4v2/project.h
```

Comment: But that prints the deleted ones as well.

Comment: I add `\M`

```git status -uno -sb | grep M\```

Comment: @kritzel_sw I just modified my command to not display the deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

To list all modified files use:

```
git show --stat --oneline HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to have the results on a single line via `-s` which can limit what is being shown.

```
git status -s
```

[image: Image of Git status -s]

*Shown under windows Terminal with Powerline/Posh git.*

---

This command is so handy in that I added it as an alias used as `git stati`

```
[alias]
   stati = !git status -s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the **modified** files, you could do this:

```sh
git log -n1 --oneline --name-status | grep '^M'
```

Answer (score 0):

All great answers; just FEI, "git checkout " (switching to or in the same branch) appears to show only modified files.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are great but Git has evolved and now provides an out-of-the-box solution for getting just the name of changed files(includes untracked)

```
git status --short
```

If you need a script-friendly output, use the recommended --porcelain flag

```
git status --short --porcelain
```

Answer (score -1):

I use `git cola`. Its a simple and elegant UI client that will show you the modified files and provide you with a diff like shot of the changes you made.

`git cola` provides you with a GUI where you can visualize which files you modified, which you staged, and even those you don't track. Your question was to use git status only I believe, but I thought git cola can help when that and other things as well. Check this web page from more info: [git-cola.github.com/screenshots.html](http://git-cola.github.com/screenshots.html)

Comment: Could you provide how that relates to my answer given i'm not familiar with this git cola. e.g. screenshots, or more detail?

Comment: it that why is was downvoted? :)
Anyway, git cola provides you with a GUI where you can visualize which files you modified, which you staged, and even those you don't track. Your question was to use git status only I believe, but I thought git cola can help when that and other things as well. Check this web page from more info: http://git-cola.github.com/screenshots.html

Comment: How to change cola's interface language?