# How to show only the modified file names and exclude the deleted ones?

Tags: git

I used the following code to get the changed file name list.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only
```

However, the result will include all the file names.
As I only want the modified ones , is there a way to exclude the deleted ones?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018533/is-it-possible-to-git-status-only-modified-files

Answer (score 4):

I think the best is to use the diff command with diff-filter applied:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM
```

This should give you the list of added and modified files (AM in diff filter) when comparing your working tree to the index.

You could also apply the --diff-filter option to show command but this one is.
To check more flags you can set on the --diff-filter option check the [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).