# No Need to show DELETED file path in " git status "

Tags: git

I am working with git and every time when i check for `$ git status` its shows

```
#        deleted:    application/abe/1/index (copy).tpl
#        deleted:    application/abe/2/index (copy).tpl
#        modified:   css/mobile.css
#        modified:   css/work.css
```

I just need to see only modified files..not deletes files. Is there any method for that?

Comment: possible dup of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018533/is-it-possible-to-git-status-only-modified-files

Comment: Definitely not s dup. Different related question with a different answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `git status | grep modified`, or `git status | grep -v deleted`.  Git itself doesn't provide an option to hide deletions from the status output, since it's unlikely that someone would want to be unaware that their next commit will delete some files from the repository.

Answer (score 7):

On windows, you may use `git status | findstr -v deleted`. Grep is not available on windows command line.