# git: show all modified files - staged and not staged

Tags: git

I need a command which gives me **all modified files** - this includes staged (i.e. newly added files) and non-staged changes - in a **plain list** which I can use in a script. While this question might sound familiar I only find commands that come close to what I want to do:

```
git ls-files -m
```

.. lists (non staged) modifications *but ignores staged and newly
added files*

```
git diff --name-only
```

.. will also *only list non staged* modifications

```
git diff --name-only --cached
```

.. lists *only staged* modifications but omits files with non-staged
modifications

```
git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no
```

.. outputs all files I want to see but *adds the status*

I could play with `git status` of course and `cut` the first entry but since I want to integrate this command in a CMake script which will be used on windows, too. So one single command would be fine..

Comment: It takes two `git diff` commands to get the list (the two you've identified).  The `git status` command runs two `git diff`-s internally. Note that it's possible to have file `foo` modified and staged, and then modified again and not-staged. (In this case `git status` shows it as `MM`.)

Comment: It looks like I can diff explicitly against `HEAD` like I've written in my answer - is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: `git diff HEAD` compares `HEAD` (the current commit) vs work-tree: it will miss files that were staged, then modified back to match the `HEAD` commit. For instance, add a line to `foo`, `git add` the result, then delete the added line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only HEAD
```

looks like what I'm looking for - but I'm not sure yet. If someone comes up with some elaboration I'll take his/her answer :)

Comment: This compares the worktree with the state of your HEAD. It may differ from what you had in mind while asking your question. The difference is for that case when you modify a file, stage it, and then undo the changes in the worktree. How do you want this case to be handled?

Comment: I tried to get the output to be on one line by using the `-z` option so I could pipe into tar, but it's showing `^@` between each file -- anyone know how to replace this with space?

Comment: @thdoan maybe this something like this? $ git diff --name-only HEAD | paste -sd " "